# Dairy Farms in Wisconsin and Minnesota

Tags: data-request, usa, research, analysis

I'm looking to get a directory of Dairy Farms in Wisconsin and Minnesota and the approx. size of each farm in heads terms?
Any idea where can I get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Census of Agriculture](https://www.agcensus.usda.gov/), [National Agricultural Statistics Service (NASS)](https://www.nass.usda.gov/), and the [ERS (Economic Research Service)](https://www.ers.usda.gov/) branches of the [USDA](https://www.usda.gov/) have most of the data you are looking for. However, I'm not sure if you can get down to the farm/number of heads level, although you should be able to get pretty close.

You can get a good feel for this here:
[Ag Census Web Maps](https://www.agcensus.usda.gov/Publications/2012/Online_Resources/Ag_Census_Web_Maps/) lets you mash them all up and get a better view (in my opinion). Here's a screenshot of Average Number of Cattle and Calves per 100 Acres of All Land in Farms: 2012[image]

Lastly, try states agricultural services website; [Wisconsin's has a directory](https://datcp.wi.gov/Documents/DairyPlantDirectory.pdf)

Comment: But this doesn't give me the directory of those farms, just aggregate figures.

Comment: the Wisconsin directory gives you exactly that. not to mention that i pointed out that i'm not sure if they give you such granular details in the usda data.